# Plotting yield curves with rCharts

Tags: r, rcharts

I have a CSV file with government and corporate yields from a country. The first row are headers, the first column I have duration in days from 1 to 5900, from the 2nd to the 7th I have yiels for Government, AAA, AA+, AA, AA- and A ratings.

At work we oversee these curves everyday to detect possible cases of bond price fixing, and we do this by plotting these curves in excel and compare it with the curves from the previous day  then crossing this information with the bonds traded the same day.

Since graphs in excel are no very interactive, I want to plot these curves using rCharts and publish them. However when I try to import the data then plot it, the file that contains the interactive chart is too heavy, and the browser crashes every time I try to load it. I think it has something to do with the way I import the data. The code is as follows:

```
    file='~/R/Projects/Yields-20130705-PEN.csv'
    pip <- read.zoo(file,index.column=1,sep=',',header=T,nrows=5900)
    colnames(pip) <- c('Sovereign','AAA','AA+','AA','AA-','A')

    pip.df <- data.frame(index(pip),coredata(100*pip))
    colnames(pip.df) <- c('Duration','Sovereign','AAA','AA+','AA','AA-','A')
    pip.melt <- melt(pip.df,id.vars=1)
    colnames(pip.melt) <- c('Duration','Curves','Yields')

    n1 <- nPlot(
      Yields~Duration,
      data = pip.melt,
      group = 'Curves',
      type = "lineWithFocusChart")

    n1
```

I see in some examples and tutorials for rChart that use a lot more data than I do and the plot doesn't crash, but I must say they have dates to sort the data. As a mentioned early, these data have as index duration expressed in days, from 1 to 5900, jumping from 1 to 1.

```
    > dput(head(aaa))
    structure(c(0.001253432, 0.001276935, 0.001300438, 0.001323942, 
    0.001347445, 0.001370948, 0.012065501, 0.012089004, 0.012112507, 
    0.01213601, 0.012159514, 0.012183017, 0.017379049, 0.017402552, 
    0.017426055, 0.017449559, 0.017473062, 0.017496565, 0.017379049, 
    0.017402552, 0.017426055, 0.017449559, 0.017473062, 0.017496565, 
    0.018015215, 0.018038718, 0.018062222, 0.018085725, 0.018109228, 
    0.018132731, 0.026837954, 0.026861458, 0.026884961, 0.026908464, 
    0.026931967, 0.026955471), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Soberana", "AAA", "AA+", "AA", "AA-", "A")), index = 1:6, class = "zoo")
```

Comment: I had no problems plotting with `head(pip)`. Is it possible to post the `csv` file or a randomized version of it someplace I can access?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39244128/Yields-20130705-PEN.csv

Comment: Thanks!!! Even when I try to publish it with slidify it gets a lot for a web browser to load the plot and most times it crashes.

Comment: It hangs for me too. Let me check if saving the data as a json file and then accessing it in the HTML works.

Comment: Externalizing data helps a bit, but the plot still chokes. The performance issue could be due to NVD3, or due to naive JS code in rCharts, and I will have to figure out which.

Comment: So is it a problem for big amounts of data? Or is it just for this case specific?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33109/discussion-between-christian-portocarrero-and-ramnath)